on click system configuration open tab not working
on this i faced this issue,
on click system configuration open tab but after click other tab magneto admin click not working i can not able click any where
enter link description here

Run once SSH command  static-content deploy
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f 

also, check on the console log for any js related error that may be possible for that issue."

You can apply the commands below to your root directory.
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento s:static-content:de -f
php bin/magento c:f

if you are using the Ubuntu system then apply the below commands.
sudo php bin/magento s:up  
sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile 
sudo php bin/magento s:static-content:de -f 
sudo php bin/magento c:f 
sudo chmod -R 777 var/ pub/ generated/

If your work is my answer then upvote me.
